# session state doesn't work in asp.net core 2.1 api project

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I created asp.net core 2.1 API project and need save all user data and permissions in session.

But when I call another API session value return `null`.

can anyone help me for this problem?

in startup.cs

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
                {
                    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                });

                services.AddSession();
                services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
                var sqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
                services.AddDbContext<QDeskDevContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString));
                DependencyInjectionConfig.AddScope(services);
                JwtTokenConfig.AddAuthentication(services, Configuration);
                services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
                });

                services.AddSignalR();
                services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("sessionHandling", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new sessionRequirement()));
                });

                services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, sessionAuthorizationHandler>();


}
```

i configration function i added   app.UseSession();

```cs
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSession();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
           app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ExcMiddleware));

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<QDeskHub>("/QDesk");
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseMvc();

        }
```

my api action

```cs
     [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult login([FromBody]LoginVM loginVM)
            {

                TryValidateModel(loginVM);
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string encPassword = common.creatHashPW(loginVM.Password);
                    TblCpUsers checkedUser = _UserService.login(loginVM.Email, encPassword);
                    if (checkedUser != null)
                    {
                            string token = _UserService.BuildToken(checkedUser, loginVM.encPassword, loginVM.isPersistent, loginVM.language);

    // here i set session value 
                            HttpContext.Session.SetString("token", token);
                            return Ok(new { token = token });
            }
           }}
```

here i want to get session value

```cs
[HttpGet]
        public object GetUserProfileData()

        {

            var token = HttpContext.Session.GetString("token") ?? string.Empty; // token return null 
            // this is my problem
            string userId = HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList().Single(d => d.Type == "id").Value;

            if (userId != null)
            {
                user user = _userService.get_user_data_by_encId(userId);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    return _stCbUserServices.GetUserById(user.userInfo.UserId);

                }
                else
                {
                    return ResultFilter.exception;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return ResultFilter.userNotFound;
            }






        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you have added the call to "UseSession()" in Configure ?

eg:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession(); // ----> Have you added this ?
    app.UseHttpContextItemsMiddleware();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: i added it my problem is when i try to get session value it returns null

Comment: It looks like you are setting a session value in server side code & then expect an API (probably JS) call to have access to the session. By default, session cookies are "HttpOnly" &  typically cannot be accessed by JS code. You could try setting the HttpOnly option to false - when Adding the Session & then see if your code works.
Also, you should use browser  tools to see if the Session cookie is actually being set upon your login method & passed back in the response. Then when calling the API, you should verify if the cookie is passed back to the server.

Comment: Having said the above, for the purpose you are trying to use the Session cookie, it is definitely not recommended. You should avoid using Session state if at all possible. There are severe restrictions on Session variables. Read about it all here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: i tried setting  "HttpOnly"  false and it not working .

Comment: i need to store user data to avoid connecting database serval times can you recommend something for me to store user data instead of session

Comment: Using a distributed cache may be a good option for this. Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis is something you can try. Without understanding your scenario a generic recommendation can't be made. But note that you would still need to implement an authentication mechanism that identifies the currently "logged in" user - & then map the user to information stored in the cache .